# This C code declares an error (segfault) when I run it

Tags: c, data-structures, segmentation-fault, doubly-linked-list

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

struct chambre {
  int num;
  struct chambre *prd;
  struct chambre *svt;
};
typedef struct chambre chambre;

struct ascenseur {
  char c;
  struct chambre *etage;
  struct ascenseur *etage_svt;
  struct ascenseur *etage_prd;
};
typedef struct ascenseur ascenseur;

ascenseur *rdch = NULL;

ascenseur *Ajout_Etage(int up) {
  ascenseur *new_Etage = NULL;
  ascenseur *etage_up = rdch;
  for (int i = 0; i < up; i++) {
    etage_up = etage_up->etage_svt;
  }

  new_Etage = malloc(sizeof(ascenseur));
  (etage_up->etage_svt)->etage_prd = new_Etage;
  new_Etage->etage_svt = (etage_up->etage_svt);
  new_Etage->etage_prd = etage_up;
  etage_up->etage_svt = new_Etage;

  new_Etage->c = 'X';

  new_Etage->etage = malloc(sizeof(chambre));
  chambre *p = new_Etage->etage;
  p->num = 1;
  p->svt = p;
  p->prd = p;

  chambre *nouv;
  chambre *pre = p;
  for (int i = 2; i < 6; i++) {
    nouv = malloc(sizeof(chambre));
    p->prd = nouv;
    nouv->num = i;
    nouv->prd = pre;
    pre->svt = nouv;
    pre = nouv;
  }
  return new_Etage;
}

int main() {
  int i;
  // ascenseur * rdch=NULL;
  ascenseur *new_rdch, *rdch_prd;

  rdch = malloc(sizeof(ascenseur));
  rdch->c = 'A';
  rdch->etage_prd = NULL;
  rdch->etage_svt = NULL;

  rdch->etage = malloc(sizeof(chambre));
  chambre *p = rdch->etage;
  p->num = 1;
  p->prd = p;
  p->svt = p;

  //=============

  chambre *nouv;
  chambre *pre = p;
  for (i = 2; i < 6; i++) {
    nouv = malloc(sizeof(chambre));
    p->prd = nouv;
    nouv->num = i;
    nouv->prd = pre;
    pre->svt = nouv;

    pre = nouv;
  }

  printf("%c -> : ", rdch->c);
  printf("%d", p->num);
  printf(" %d ", (p->svt)->num);

  printf("\n_______________________ : \n");

  //==================================================
  rdch_prd = rdch;
  for (int j = 1; j < 6; j++) {
    new_rdch = malloc(sizeof(ascenseur));

    new_rdch->c = 'A' + j;
    new_rdch->etage_prd = rdch_prd;
    new_rdch->etage_svt = NULL;

    rdch_prd = new_rdch;

    new_rdch->etage = malloc(sizeof(chambre));

    p = new_rdch->etage;
    p->num = 1;
    p->prd = p;
    p->svt = p;

    //=============

    pre = p;
    for (i = 2; i < 6; i++) {
      nouv = malloc(sizeof(chambre));
      p->prd = nouv;
      nouv->num = i;
      nouv->prd = pre;
      pre->svt = nouv;

      pre = nouv;
    }

    printf("%c -> : ", new_rdch->c);
    printf("%d", p->num);
    printf(" %d ", (p->svt)->num);
    printf("\n_______________________ : \n\n");
  }
  ascenseur *etage_up = Ajout_Etage(3);
  printf("\n\n");

  printf("%c ==> : ", etage_up->c);
  // printf("%d ",(etage_up->etage)->num);

  return 0;
}
```

I declare the `rdch` pointer as a global VAR initialized with "NULL".
After that, by the process in the `main` function, the `rdch` pointer has a value now (not NULL).
THE DEBUGGER declare the error in the line `etage_up=etage_up-\>etage_svt;`

I don't know if the function "Ajout_Etage" takes the etage_up as NULL then the etage_svt of etage_up does not exist ....so if I'm right, why does the `etage_up` take the NULL value when the `rdch` pointer by the process in the `main` function takes a real address with real build.

Comment: Use the debugger to follow the code up until the segfault.  Track the value of `etage_up` and the solution will likely be obvious.

Comment: Looks like `etage_svt` is never assigned anything except `NULL`.  Why would it *not* be `NULL`??

Comment: @Jason maybe the OP doesn't quite understand pointers that well, and thinks it's assigned somewhere in the loop, when in fact it isn't.

Answer (score 0):

1. Your program segfaults in `Ajout_Etage()` as `etage_up` is NULL:

```
    ascenseur *etage_up = rdch;
    for (int i = 0; i < up; i++) {
        etage_up = etage_up->etage_svt;
    }
```

`up = 3` but there is only 1 node in the global variable `rdch`.

2. If you add a `&& etage_up` to fix the above then it segfault in `(etage_up->etage_svt)->etage_prd = new_Etage;` for the same reason.

`Ajout_Etage(3)` presumes you have 3 nodes in the `etage_up->etage_svt` chain but in `main()` you only initialize one node:

```
    rdch = malloc(sizeof(ascenseur));
    rdch->c = 'A';
    rdch->etage_prd = NULL;
    rdch->etage_svt = NULL;
```

then later you do:

```
    rdch_prd = rdch;
    for (int j = 1; j < 6; j++) {
        new_rdch = malloc(sizeof(ascenseur));

        new_rdch->c = 'A' + j;
        new_rdch->etage_prd = rdch_prd;
        new_rdch->etage_svt = NULL;

        rdch_prd = new_rdch;
        // ...
```

which doesn't change `rdch`.

I suggest you break your code into smaller functions, avoid global variables, and in general minimize the scope of variables.  You also want to use English if you want the largest audience here on Stack Overflow.

Answer (score 0):

When you use the debugger, you should try to find out not only *where* the crash happens, but also *when*. If you step into your code statement-by-statement you should notice that yes, you fault on `etage_up = etage_up->etage_svt`, but on the second iteration of the loop. This means the problem has nothing to do with `rdch` (the original value pointed by `etage_up`), but instead with `rdch->etage_svt` (the value pointed by `etage_up` after the first iteration).

And in fact, if you inspect `rdch->etage_svt` in the debugger, you will notice that it's 0, and trying to dereference it results in a crash. To solve your bug, you will need to assign `rdch->etage_svt` to something valid.